# python2.7.6 Initialize a big dictionary but Memory would be used up

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, freeze

Excuse my English,

python version:2.7.6
desktop: 4 cpu-core 8G memory
**script1:**

```
a = {}
a['test1'] = 12345
a['test2'] = 12456
........
and so on
........
a['test4075096'] = 45637
```

**script2:**

```
for i in range(0,4075096):
    a['test' + str(i)] = i
```

**result**

When I run the script2, it complete very quickly
When I run the script1, it needs large mem and cpu,and my desktop stuck

So does anyone know the reasons behind this phenomenon

Comment: You need `a = {}` at the start of script2 as well.  The machine's RAM size is important, but also the virtual memory available.  This in part depends on the OS word size (32/64 bit, for example) and the Python implementation.  How have you monitored the memory and CPU usage?

Comment: I forgot to copy the initialization code, but run my notebook on 2 contains initialization script, I notebook is X64 architecture，thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of that in first code, python has to read your code line by line and load CONST values to memory, while in second part you already have specified the values which would be assigned,and python will created them in memory. So all that python needs to do is iterating over the `range` object and assign the values to keys.

You can see this behaviour by calling `dis.dis()` on your functions which demonstrates the relative bytecodes for you:

```
>>> def foo1():
...   a = {}
...   a['test1'] = 12345
...   a['test2'] = 12456
... 

>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dis.dis(foo1)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (12345)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('test1')
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        

  4          16 LOAD_CONST               3 (12456)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 ('test2')
             25 STORE_SUBSCR        
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> 

>>> def foo2():
...   a = {}
...   for i in range(1,10):
...        a['test + str(i)'] = i
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo2)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              33 (to 42)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             21 GET_ITER            
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                16 (to 41)
             25 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  4          28 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             31 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             34 LOAD_CONST               3 ('test + str(i)')
             37 STORE_SUBSCR        
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   41 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> 
>>>
```

If you increase the assignment you can see that the relative bytecode will increases as well :

```
>>> def foo1():
...    a = {}
...    a['test1'] = 12345
...    a['test2'] = 12456
...    a['test3'] = 12457
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo1)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (12345)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('test1')
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        

  4          16 LOAD_CONST               3 (12456)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 ('test2')
             25 STORE_SUBSCR        

  5          26 LOAD_CONST               5 (12457)
             29 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             32 LOAD_CONST               6 ('test3')
             35 STORE_SUBSCR        
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: but constants all add up to about the size of a few megabytes , it does not seem to cause memory problems，Is not that where I understand the wrong